# Должен ли я вовремя сравнений использовать приведение типов (float) , если имеются разные значения 'string', 'integer', 'double'?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть большой код который получается после `json_decode()` . Нужно сделать сравнение параметров которые могут иметь разные типы `string`, `integer`, `double`,

> Как известно в php например 9 не равно 9.0.
>   Но

```
float(9) === 9.0 // true
```

Для той цели использую приведение типов (`float`).

Правильная ли эта практика, есть ли другой выход, ввиду большого кода использую много (`float`) операторов не отразится ли это на производительности веб сайта ?

Answer (score 0):

Политика контроля типов всегда правильная (явное лучше чем не явное). Конечно же с умом, и там где это вам нужно. Не стоит пихать проверку везде, всё таки php не зря не имеет строгой типизации, есть свои плюсы. Только используйте конструкции языка (int)$var, (float)$var ..., они работают быстрее чем вызов функций intval, floatval ...

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать использовать нестрогое сравнение "==" вместо строго "===", хотя не лучший вариант